# Ruby on rails выдает ошибку

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
$ rails server
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/gem_helpers.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::GemHelpers::GENERIC_CACHE
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb:5: warning: previous definition of GENERIC_CACHE was here
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/gem_helpers.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::GemHelpers::GENERICS
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb:6: warning: previous definition of GENERICS was here
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/gem_helpers.rb:52: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::GemHelpers::PlatformMatch
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb:52: warning: previous definition of PlatformMatch was here
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'sqlite3 x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:255:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:255:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:49:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:22:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:258:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Роман/Desktop/Изучение-prog/RUBY/G_ronr/first-app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Какая ОС? `bundle install` прошёл без ошибок?

Comment: И добавьте Gemfile в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Стоит попробовать

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' do
  # your gems
end
```